# Problems displaying the results in a servlet(for arrays,java)

Tags: java, servlets

I'm having a little trouble in the servlet. I run it from the Apache Tomcat. So I run it at startup, I have a console, in general everything is standard, but here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class servletss extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();


        File file = new File("C:\\prov");
        String list[] = file.list();


        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>testservlets</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        /*
        * начало вывода
        */

        ArrayList<String> sizel = new ArrayList<String>();
    sizel = pagef();
    int sizelist;
    sizelist = sizel.size();


        int pageint = 1;// номер страницы


    ArrayList<String> sizetris = new ArrayList<String>();

    int startlist = (pageint - 1) * 30;
        int endlist = (sizel.size() >= (startlist + 30)) ? (startlist + 30): sizel.size();

    sizetris.addAll(sizel.subList(startlist, endlist));

    double startdouble = 10.0;// конец показа страниц
        int endint = (int) (pageint * 10);// конечное число пользователя
    double allpage = sizelist / 3;// число страниц всего
        double page = allpage / startdouble;// деление страниц
    double lsc = Math.ceil(page);
        String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        if (endint > lsc * 10) {
            out.println("страниц не найдено");
        } else {
            out.println("<div class=\"pagen\">" + pageint + "</div>");

                        String str = paginate(sizetris, endint * 3);
            out.println("<div class=\"bloctext\">" + str + separator + "</div>");

            out.println("<div class=\"pagen\">" + pageint + "</div>");
        }




        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            out.println("<a href=\"http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=" + i + "\" str=\"" + i + "\">" + i + "</a>");

        }
        out.println("</body>");

        out.println("</html>");
    }


    static <T> String paginate(List<T> pages, int pagesPerOut) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i += pagesPerOut) {
            System.out.println(paginate(pages, i, pagesPerOut));
        }
        return "";

    }


    static <T> List<T> paginate(List<T> pages, int start, int count) {
        int end = start + count > pages.size() ? pages.size() : start + count;
        return pages.subList(start, end);

    }
        /*
         * метод для возвращения массива страниц
         */

    static ArrayList<String> pagef() {
        ArrayList<String> page = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String s = null;
        File file = new File("C:\\prov");
        String list[] = file.list();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                File fileread = new File("C:\\prov\\" + list[i]);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(fileread), "UTF-8"));
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    page.add(s + "\n");
                }
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
        }

        return page;

    }
}
```

I started it and now this part of the code:

```
out.println("<div class=\"bloctext\">" + str + separator + "</div>");
```

She had to take 30 stitches, but when I run the code, I can not see anything, but looking at the console I saw there my 30 stitch)) in the console Tomcat))
Why the result of the work there, and not on the page into a servlet?
You have other problems in your code, do not look, just tell me please how to fix this?
Everything is correct, the servlet is in the correct folder, here web.xml code file, just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servletss</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servletss</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servletss</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servletss</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thank you in advance for your answers))

**UPD**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class servletss extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out;

            out = res.getWriter();



        File file = new File("C:\\prov");
        String list[] = file.list();


        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>testservlets</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        /*
        * начало вывода
        */

        ArrayList<String> sizel = new ArrayList<String>();
    sizel = pagef();
    int sizelist;
    sizelist = sizel.size();


        int pageint = 1;// номер страницы


    ArrayList<String> sizetris = new ArrayList<String>();

    int startlist = (pageint - 1) * 30;
        int endlist = (sizel.size() >= (startlist + 30)) ? (startlist + 30): sizel.size();

    sizetris.addAll(sizel.subList(startlist, endlist));

    double startdouble = 10.0;// конец показа страниц
        int endint = (int) (pageint * 10);// конечное число пользователя
    double allpage = sizelist / 3;// число страниц всего
        double page = allpage / startdouble;// деление страниц
    double lsc = Math.ceil(page);
        String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        if (endint > lsc * 10) {
            out.println("страниц не найдено");
        } else {
            out.println("<div class=\"pagen\">" + pageint + "</div>");

                        String str = paginate(sizetris, endint * 3);
            out.println("<div class=\"bloctext\">" + str + separator + "</div>");

            out.println("<div class=\"pagen\">" + pageint + "</div>");
        }




        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            out.println("<a href=\"http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=" + i + "\" str=\"" + i + "\">" + i + "</a>");

        }
        out.println("</body>");

        out.println("</html>");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    static <T> String paginate(List<T> pages, int pagesPerOut) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i += pagesPerOut) {
            System.out.println(paginate(pages, i, pagesPerOut));
        }
        return "";

    }


    static <T> List<T> paginate(List<T> pages, int start, int count) {
        int end = start + count > pages.size() ? pages.size() : start + count;
        return pages.subList(start, end);

    }
        /*
         * метод для возвращения массива страниц
         */

    static ArrayList<String> pagef() {
        ArrayList<String> page = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String s = null;
        File file = new File("C:\\prov");
        String list[] = file.list();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                File fileread = new File("C:\\prov\\" + list[i]);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(fileread), "UTF-8"));
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    page.add(s + "\n");
                }
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
        }

        return page;

    }
}
```

**UPD 2**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testservlets</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pagen">1</div>
<div class="bloctext">
 //There must be a conclusion, but it in a servlet
</div>
<div class="pagen">1</div>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=0" str="0">0</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=1" str="1">1</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=2" str="2">2</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=3" str="3">3</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=4" str="4">4</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=5" str="5">5</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=6" str="6">6</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=7" str="7">7</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=8" str="8">8</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=9" str="9">9</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=10" str="10">10</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=11" str="11">11</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=12" str="12">12</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=13" str="13">13</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=14" str="14">14</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=15" str="15">15</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=16" str="16">16</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=17" str="17">17</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=18" str="18">18</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=19" str="19">19</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=20" str="20">20</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=21" str="21">21</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=22" str="22">22</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=23" str="23">23</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=24" str="24">24</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: are you saying your servlet is not printing anything on page but printing on console?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfj6T.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in `doGet()` you are not doing `out.flush()` and `out.close()`.

`PrintWriter` is type of **Buffered writer** and when you say `out.print()` it writes to **buffer** instead of actual **stream**. To make the content of **buffer** flow to the **stream** (in your case the stream of your `HttpServletResponse`) you need to invoke `out.flush()`

EDIT: You can call these methods after `out.println("</html>");` (at the end of your `doGet()` method) like this,

```
out.println("</html>");
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry, of course, but you could not tell where to insert         out.flush()

Comment: I'm just not experienced with it, where to insert the code? of what?

Comment: exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Comment: I should probably all surround the block try

Comment: Please check by latest edit.. actually we dont have to catch IOException

Comment: All else fails, add anything you suggest, all displayed in the console again ((

Comment: After this servlet finishes its execution, can you see any content when you do your Browser-> View Source?

Comment: No, it did not help ( see to UPD 2

Comment: I see that the response is getting "written" to the HttpResponse's stream, so its not the problem with "writing response". There must be some problem with the logic written inside your servlet.  I see that the `paginate(List, int)` method is returning "" (empty string). If you want to write something there, you must return something from `paginate(List, int)` method?